# How to setup apache jackrabbit to use MySQL DB to store metadata and Filesystem to store files associated with that metadata

Tags: java, mysql, weblogic11g, jackrabbit

I want to configure Apache JackRabbit in such a way that all metadata should be stored in a MyQSL database and files associated with that metadata to be stored in the file system.

Use case: I will get some files in Pdf/Word format and the user will also send properties like author, topic etc..  for these files. I want to store those properties in a database and the actual file in the filesystem.

My question is: is it possible to do so?
If yes: How do I configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 1.4, Apache Jackrabbit defines the concept of a Data Store, i.e. a separate storage for binary properties. You can define a Data Store in the [repository.xml](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jackrabbit-configuration.html) file. Further details about the Data Store are in [this wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore).

In particular, you would like to define your Data Store as an instance of `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore`. The aforementioned wiki page contains an example configuration for this implementation of Data Store.